# How to broadcast message to a single client using nestjs?

Tags: websocket, chat, nestjs

I am using nestjs websockets to build a chat app for a multi-vendor application but whenever I broadcast/emit a message from the server to the client, it gets broadcasted to all the clients. Is it possible to emit a message to a single client? And how to do that?

```
export class ChatGateway implements OnGatewayInit {
    constructor(private conversationService: ConversationService) {}
    @WebSocketServer()
    server: Server;

    @SubscribeMessage('sendMessage')
    async handleMessage(
        client: Socket,
        payload: {
            senderProfileId: ID;
            recieverProfileId: ID;
            conversationId: ID;
            message: string;
            createdAt: Date;
        },
    ) {
        await this.conversationService.createMessage({
            message: payload.message,
            createdAt: payload.createdAt,
            senderProfileId: payload.senderProfileId as string,
            conversationId: payload.conversationId as string,
        });
        // Want to emit this to a single client
        this.server.emit('recieveMessage', payload);
    }
}
```

Currently, I am using the **recieverProfileId** to make sure if the message is displayed to the correct reciever.

Comment: Please post some part of the code that you wish to be changed from broadcast to single client/

Comment: Did you get any solution ?

Comment: this.server.to("client id").emit('recieveMessage', payload);

Answer (score -2):

server side:

```
@SubscribeMessage('message')
onEnvent(@MessageBody() message: any){
    this.server.to(message.to).emit("message", message);
}
```

client:

```
socket.emit('message', { to: socket.id, data: message })
```